# jQuery using index to find an elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a search function for my website and I am getting there; just having a problem selecting the index of the items.

This is what I have ATM:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.inputs input', function (event) {
  var $inputVal = $(this).val();
  var $inputListVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').index(this);
  var $trList = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children();
  $.each($trList, function( index ) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('inputs') && !$(this).hasClass('first-item')) {
        var tdList = $(this).children().index($inputListVal); <!-- This is whats not working ATM -->
        console.log(tdList);
    };
  });
});
```

Question 1: Any ideas on why it's not working?

Question 2: How would I do the search side of it?  e.g. if they input `pi` it will show all things starting with them 2 letters (pie, pig and so on)?

```
    <tr class="inputs">
        <th><input id="tick-all" type="checkbox" name="tick" value="download"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="box_number"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="client_name"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="make"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="qty"></th>
        <th><input class="big-input" type="text" name="descnption"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="width"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="depth"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="height"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="colour"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="order_number"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="quality"></th>
        <th><input class="big-input" type="text" name="picture"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="Order"></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        require_once('connent.php');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM client_info";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='download-tick' value='download'></td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Box'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Client'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Make'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Descnption'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Width'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Depth'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Height'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Colour'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['OrderNo'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Quality'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Picture'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($row['Order'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>23<br><input class='small-input' type='text' name='Order'></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        //echo $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    ?>
```

Comment: Please add your html too so that we can check

Comment: with out html details it will be difficult to recreate the issue, could you please add the sample in Plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.index()` function takes in a selector to return the index of the element. In this case it looks like you want to select the item with a known index which you have stored in $inputListVal.

You should use the `.eq()` function or just square bracket notation:

```
var tdList = $(this).children().eq($inputListVal)
```

or

```
var tdList = $(this).children()[$inputListVal]
```

Either of these will select the element from the collection at the given index.

EDIT: Now that you have provided a more complete question it is a bit easier to see what you are trying to do. I have just written this quickly and tested it very briefly.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.inputs input', function (event) {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    var columnIndex = $(this).closest('th').index(); //Get the index of the current column
    var $trList = $(this).parent().parent().siblings(); //Select all TR except this header row
    $.each($trList, function() {
        var $td = $(this).children().eq(columnIndex); //Get the right td
        if (($td.text().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) || searchTerm.length < 1) { //Check if the search term is in the td text
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="inputs">
        <th><input id="tick-all" type="checkbox" name="tick" value="download"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="box_number"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="client_name"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="make"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="qty"></th>
        <th><input class="big-input" type="text" name="descnption"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="width"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="depth"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="height"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="colour"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="order_number"></th>
        <th><input class="md-input" type="text" name="quality"></th>
        <th><input class="big-input" type="text" name="picture"></th>
        <th><input class="small-input" type="text" name="Order"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='download-tick' value='download'></td>
      <td>Box 1</td>
      <td>Geoff Stains</td>
      <td>Make One</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='download-tick' value='download'></td>
      <td>Box 2</td>
      <td>Andy Ball</td>
      <td>Make Two</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='download-tick' value='download'></td>
      <td>Box 3</td>
      <td>Linda Smith</td>
      <td>Make One</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='download-tick' value='download'></td>
      <td>Box 4</td>
      <td>Tom Hope</td>
      <td>Make Three</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='download-tick' value='download'></td>
      <td>Box 5</td>
      <td>Steve Smith</td>
      <td>Make Two</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tryed both of them but when I console.log(tdList); its showing -1 any idea why ?

Comment: That most likely means that there is nothing at the index you are selecting. $inputListVa is porbably wrong. In fact I think I see a problem, let me update my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to do search side of things now and I don't really understand where I'm meant to use your code.
This is what I have now
`        if (!$(this).hasClass('inputs') && !$(this).hasClass('first-item')) {
            var tdList = $(this).children().eq($inputListVal)
            var hasText = $("td:contains('"+ $inputVal +"')");
            if (tdList || hasText) {
                console.log('Yes');
            } else {
                console.log('No');
            }
        };`
But that's not working any ideas ?

Comment: I've shown you how to check if an element contains your search text. It will return true or false so probably use it in an if. As I have said, if you provided more of your code and HTML I could help you further.

Comment: I have added some of my HTML that I'm trying to do the search on Is that all you needed to help me ?

Comment: I've edited my answer again and added some code that might help.